A movie about 3 soldiers going crazy in a cabin
What film is this?!
We're pretty sure that a man shoots a rabbit at the start and it explodes. The film has 3 soldiers in a cabin that think it's still the war. Some kind of gas gets released and they all start to go a bit crazy. One of them goes out to find some other soldiers in a neighbouring cabin but they all already went crazy and killed each other. Of the two left behind, one ties the other up and also he starts imagining spiders. They're getting their power from some kind of radioactive generator, and the climax of the film takes place near this.

No idea, but it sounds epic.

The film you are describing is "Outpost 11"

Set in an alternative past where steam power still rules the world,
  outpost 11 is the story of three soldiers manning a remote listening
  post in the Arctic Circle. One day the warning light goes off
  unexpectedly and their world is plunged into chaos. Albert , Mason,
  Graham must fight the isolation, madness and arctic spiders to
  survive.


Can you add any info why this is the answer?
